# Toggling button color on click in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am working on a gomoku style game using Vue.js, and I am stuck. When one of the buttons is clicked, it should change the `background-color` of that button to green, then if I click on another open spot, it should change the `background-color` to blue (thereby simulating each player's move). The problem with my program so far is that when I click on a button, it changes every empty spot to green instead of just the one I clicked. I am trying to do this in my `index.html`:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="slots in board">
   <ul id="board">
    <li v-for="slot in slots">
      <button @click="handleClick($index, $parent.$index)"
      :class="{'green': turn}"
      >{{slot}}</button></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Then in my `styles.css`:

```
.green{
   background-color: #41B883;
}
.blue{
   background-color: #35495E;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in:

```
<button @click="handleClick($index, $parent.$index)"
      :class="{'green': turn}"
      >{{slot}}</button>
```

you are binding green class to every button just because `turn` is true .
You should also check if the point in this array corresponding to that button is marked as checked.

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<button @click="handleClick($index, $parent.$index)"
   v-bind:class="{ 'green': isGreen($index, $parent.$index), 'blue': isBlue($index, $parent.$index)}">
            {{slot}}
</button>
```

use 2 functions to check which class to bind.

in JS:

```
handleClick: function(index, parent){
      this.turn = !this.turn;
      this.turn ? this.board[parent][index] = greenDisk : this.board[parent][index]= blueDisk; 
    },
isGreen: function(index,parent){
 return (this.board[parent][index] == greenDisk);
},
isBlue: function(idx1,idx2){
 return !(this.turn == null) && (this.board[idx2][idx1] == blueDisk);
}
```

Why I check `this.turn` is not `null` in `isBlue`?
Because when You click button 2 variables change - `turn` and `board`.
Unfortunately vue is not very good when it comes to observing changes in arrays (push etc are ok). So it wont fire any reactivity magic with class bindings... unless we also use `turn` variable in one of those functions. These way vue knows that when variable `turn` changes (every click) it should also revalidate class bindings.

codepen:
http://codepen.io/lukpep/pen/KMgaNP

Comment: Would I do that checking inside the template or as a method in the vue instance?

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!